# upload java/spring/hibernate web application on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to upload my java web application with local database on aws elastic beanstalk.
What I did so far:

1. I have an account on aws
2. I created an application on aws beanstalk
3. Launched new environment for this.

But none of these work.  anyone Can tell me the necessary steps , please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Now it is working , what i did
1.upload war file and creating an environment for this,check your WAR file working or not locally otherwise it may create health check problem on amazon.
2.creating database in rds.
3.both should be in same region.
4.check EC2 it creates new instance for it or not, if yes it will work fine.
5. now click on your application url provide by aws.